# Can I get load a PDFont from a font name as string?

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I wondered if there is a way to load a PDType1Font by the font name.
In the 1.8.x versions, you could just load a font by a string  [static PDType1Font  getStandardFont(String name)
A convenience method to get one of the standard 14 font from name.](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.17/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDType1Font.html#PDType1Font-org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary-)
Is there a way to do this in the 2.0.x versions?

Comment: No, but what prevents you from recreating this from the 1.8 source code? Look for `STANDARD_14` in https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/1.8/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDType1Font.java?view=markup

Comment: I try not to construct something around the library. But it seems that I have no other choice. (In the 2.0 version they removed the `STANDARD_14` Attribute. Now there is no way of iterating over the fonts internally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does still exist in `TextToPDF.java` however it is all private. I would follow the suggestion of mkl: Just add a PdfUtil.java to your code where you do the following:

```
public class PdfUtils{

 private static final Map<String, PDType1Font> STANDARD_14 = new HashMap<String, PDType1Font>();

 static{
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.TIMES_ITALIC.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.TIMES_ITALIC);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD_ITALIC.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD_ITALIC);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.HELVETICA.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.HELVETICA);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD_OBLIQUE.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD_OBLIQUE);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.COURIER.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.COURIER);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.COURIER_OBLIQUE.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.COURIER_OBLIQUE);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD_OBLIQUE.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD_OBLIQUE);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.SYMBOL.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.SYMBOL);
    STANDARD_14.put(PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS.getBaseFont(), PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS);
 }
 
 private PdfUtils(){}

 public static PDType1Font getStandardFont(String name){
  return STANDARD_14.get(name);
 }
}
```